# Example a distribution of finite order which is not tempered

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

I am looking for an example of a distribution of finite order that is not a tempered distribution. Could anyone help me with an example.

It is known that any tempered distribution is of finite order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution corresponding to the $L^{1,loc}$ function $e^{x^2}$.